# Object and Timer AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, timer, flash-cs6

I have a question about TIMER in AS3

i have a zombie object on my stage, i want him to come and attack the HERO.

what i want to do is:

1. the zombie walks toward the hero
2. When he is close enough to attack, he proceeds to attack.
3. **the problem :** i want him to attack only **ONCE every 5 seconds**, so that the hero has a chance to hit him back.  The problem is i am not familiar with timer, and i still couldn't find any tips / tuts / answers that would help me.  I don't know where should I put the timer, in a new timer function or in my zombie function.

thank you :)

here's the code

```
if (zombie.x>hero.x+50)
{
    zombie.x-=5;
    zombie.scaleX=-1;

    if(zombie.x<hero.x+100){
        zombie.gotoAndStop("attack"); 
        //so that the zombie attacks when the hero is in range

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this :

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(5000);//that's 5 second

if (zombie.x>hero.x+50)
{
    zombie.x-=5;
    zombie.scaleX=-1;

    if(zombie.x<hero.x+100){
        attack();
    }
}

function attack(  ) : void
{
  // attack the first time
  zombie.gotoAndStop("attack"); 

 //than launch the timer
  timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, repeatAttack );
  timer.start();
}

//will be called every 5000 ms == 5 sec
function repeatAttack ( event : TimerEvent ) : void
{
 zombie.gotoAndStop("attack"); 
}

//if you want to stop the attack you can use this function for example

function stopAttack() : void
{
   timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, repeatAttack );
   timer.stop();//stop timer
   timer.reset();//resetCount to zero   
}
```

I hope this will help you solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You should define "idle", "walking" and "attacking" animations on your zombie, so far I only see your zombie to switch into "attacking" posture and staying there. Also, make your Zombie into a class, so that it will control its own animation, knowing when to attack and when to stop attacking (going back to idle animation). And finally, have a flag "can this zombie attack again", that will be set to true when zombie attacks, and call `flash.utils.setTimeout()` with proper parameters to invoke a function that will reset this flag. This time-based function will do for a simple one-time call, until you would learn Actionscript better.

Comment: i have "walking" and "attacking" stance, i thought i don't need the "idle" since the zombie will go on and on without stopping.  But thanks to you I know that I was wrong, thanks a lot!